# When is the render() called in a class that extends Component?

Tags: reactjs

What refreshes the view in react or is the code always live displayed?

I have a function called removeAdmin and makeAdmin which adds and removes users as Admins and then when a user is an admin the render of Member component renders and admin shield logo. It works fine but I'm wondering whether render is being triggered each time I change the UI using a function or if render is live listening to changes in it's components?

```
class MemberList extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        members: [],
        loading: false,
        administrators: []
    }
    this.makeAdmin = this.makeAdmin.bind(this)
    this.removeAdmin = this.removeAdmin.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({loading:true})
    fetch('https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=12')
    .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => json.results)
        .then(members => this.setState({
            members,
            loading:false
        }))
}

makeAdmin(email){
    const administrators = [
        ...this.state.administrators,
        email
    ]
    this.setState({administrators})
}

removeAdmin(email){
    const administrators = this.state.administrators.filter(
            adminEmail => adminEmail !== email
        )
        this.setState({administrators})

}


render() {
    const { members, loading } = this.state
    return (
        <div className="member-list">
            <h1>Society Members</h1>

            {
                (loading) ? 
                    <span> loading...</span>:
                    <span>{members.length} members</span>
            }

                { (members.length)?
                members.map(
                (member, i) => 
                    <Member key={i}
                            // This admin prop is worked out by enumerating through the administrator
                            // array with some(). some() passes in the enumerators, checking whether 
                            // the current member in members.map() exists in the administrators array
                            // and returns admin=true if so.
                            admin={this.state.administrators.some(
                                adminEmail => adminEmail === member.email
                                )}
                            name={member.name.first + '' + member.name.last}
                            email={member.email}
                            thumbnail={member.picture.thumbnail}
                            makeAdmin={this.makeAdmin}
                            removeAdmin={this.removeAdmin}/>
                 ):
                <span>Currently 0 members</span>
            }


        </div>
    )
```

and the Member component:

```
class Member extends Component {

componentWillMount(){
this.style={
    backgroundColor: 'grey'
}
}
render() {

const { name, thumbnail, email, admin, makeAdmin, removeAdmin } = this.props
return (

    <div className="member" style={this.style}>
    <h1>{ name } {(admin) ? <FaShield/> : null}</h1>
    <div>
        <img src={ thumbnail }/>
    </div>
    <div>
    {
        (admin)? 
                <Button title="Make Admin" onClick={() => removeAdmin(email) } color="#841584"> Remove Admin </Button>
:
    <Button title="Make Admin" onClick={ () => makeAdmin(email) } color="#841584"> Make Admin </Button>

    }
    <a href={`mailto:${ email }`}><p> {email} </p></a>
    </div>

    </div>


)
}
}

export default Member
```

Comment: What you've just asked ( `I'm wondering whether render is being triggered each time I change the UI using a function or if render is live listening to changes in it's components?` ) is a really basic React question, and you could have found the answer in 5 mins by Googling it.

Answer (score 2):

What triggers a new render on components is when the state changes or when receiving new properties.

There are two main objects that drive the render in each component, the `this.props` and the `this.state`. If any of this objects gets updated then the `render` method gets executed.

The `this.props` object gets updated whenever you send new properties to the childrens. `this.state` gets updated using the `this.setState` method.

That being said, it's really important to keep track of the properties you send to the children, as a rule of thumb I always recommend not using the spread operator to pass props to the children, for example:

```
<Parent>
  <Child {...this.props} />
</Parent>
```

I'd avoid that pattern because if any of the props changes, than all props are sent to the child. Instead I recommend sending only what the children needs.

```
<Parent>
  <Child some={this.props.value} />
</Parent>
```

You need to be very careful *when* you need to render your component, otherwise it's so easy to re-render everything! Which will lead to performance issues.

Comment: Your a star, thanks @Crysfel, exactly what I needed to know

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you define your component `render` method to be.
It can change based on the `state` or `props` that you give it.

Less frequent, but you can [check out](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) `shouldComponentUpdate` as it allows you to overwrite the method to give it more “smarts” if you need the performance boost.